# Can I serialize a hibernate session and then deserialize it back to get the session object?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, serialization

I need a functionality where the user can cancel the running query if she prefers, So I thought that I would serialize the hibernate session and then deserialize it back to cancel that specific query.

So I did something like:

1. Serialize and set it in the DB.
2. Get it back, and then call **session.cancelQuery()**.

Below is the code I use:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
Object o = in.readObject();
Session ss = (Session) o;
```

But this gives me an exception at **readObject()**:

```
java.io.InvalidObjectException: could not resolve session factory during session deserialization [uuid=95d6a048-677b-42f0-9b9f-7e62fd68b533, name=null]
```

So I wanted to know, if it is even possible to serialize and deserialize a hibernate session object.

Edit:
Well I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11282151), but not sure if this is correct or not!

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you really want to store the database session inside the database?

Comment: @vojta yes, this I want to store the serialized session object in the DB and then deserialize it back to session object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible  A hibernate session is used to get a physical connection to the database, which means network layer is involved. It uses a socket, a network stack, the underlying hardware - and all of them are system specific and not managed by JVM.

Serialization is only good if you are dealing with the data.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide a source for this, if there is one :) ?, so that I can read more about it.

Comment: A source for what? Sockets by design is an OS level interpretation than a JVM property. Moreover, resources cannot be serialized and data can be. That is what Serialization is supposed for. A simple google search will help you . See these in the mean time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851070/java-what-can-and-what-cant-be-serialized
http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/serialization.php